# How to show flash.message in Grails after AJAX call

Tags: ajax, grails, grails-2.0

I want to show some flash message after completion of AJAX call. I am doing like this ..

Controller Action --

```
def subscribe()
{
    def subscribe = new Subscriber()
    subscribe.email = params.subscribe
    if (subscribe.save())
    {
        flash.message = "Thanks for your subscribtion"
    }

}
```

View Part --

```
Subscribe :
    <g:formRemote onSuccess="document.getElementById('subscribeField').value='';" url="[controller: 'TekEvent', action: 'subscribe']" update="confirm" name="updateForm">
       <g:textField name="subscribe" placeholder="Enter your Email" id="subscribeField" />
       <g:submitButton name="Submit" />
    </g:formRemote >
    <div id="confirm">
       <g:if test="${flash.message}">
           <div class="message" style="display: block">${flash.message}</div>
       </g:if>
    </div>
```

My AJAX working fine but it is not showing me flash.message. After refresh page it displaying message. How to solve it ?

Comment: Short answer - flash is not for ajax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use ajax your page content isn't re-parsed, so your code:

```
<g:if test="${flash.message}">
  <div class="message" style="display: block">${flash.message}</div>
</g:if>
```

will not run again.

So I agree with @James comment, flash is not the better option to you.

If you need to update your view, go with JSON. Grails already have a [converter](http://grails.org/Converters+Reference) that can be used to this:

```
if (subscribe.save()) {
  render ([message: "Thanks for your subscribtion"] as JSON)
}
```

And your view:

```
<g:formRemote onSuccess="update(data)" url="[controller: 'TekEvent', action: 'subscribe']"  name="updateForm">
  <g:textField name="subscribe" placeholder="Enter your Email" id="subscribeField" />
  <g:submitButton name="Submit" />
</g:formRemote >

<script type='text/javascript'>
  function update(data) {
    $('#subscribeField').val('');
    $('#confirm').html(data.message);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have couple options, 
First you can try to return the message from your controller in a form of json or a map and render it on the screen your self using javascript libraries, which is a bit different if you want to use Grails ajax tags.

The other option is using a plugin like [one-time-data](http://grails.org/plugin/one-time-data) , which

> **Summary** A safe replacement for "flash" scope where you stash data in
>   the session which can only be read once, but at any point in the
>   future of the session provided you have the "id" required.
>
> **Description**
>   This plugin provides a multi-window safe alternative to flash scope
>   that makes it possible to defer accessing the data until any future
>   request (so long as the session is preserved).
>   [more](http://grails.org/plugin/one-time-data)

Hope it helps