# GRAILS : How to render with template and message

Tags: ajax, grails

Currently, I have already a working AJAX call that will be sent to the server. The controller will parse the data and return something like this :

```
    render(template: "/myProject/myProjectTemplate",
            model: [ d1 : value1,
                     d2 : value2,
                     d3 : value3
            ]);
    return
```

The code is perfectly working. But I need another data from server. This is for the error/success message. But based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920323/how-to-show-flash-message-in-grails-after-ajax-call). I couldn't pass `flash.message` when using AJAX. So they suggested using JSON. There comes the problem, I couldn't think of any way to pass the template and the message(flash) at the same time.

Is there a way to pass both template and the message at the same time to the user ?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
import grails.converters.JSON

class MyController {

    def test() {
        String htmlContent = g.render([template: "/myProject/myProjectTemplate", model: [d1: value1, d2: value2, d3: value3]])

        Map responseData = [htmlContent: htmlContent, message1: "Hello", additionalData: "Just an example"]

        render(responseData as JSON)
    }
}
```

Now, at the receiving end:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/my/test',
    success: function(data) {
        $("#my-div").html(data.htmlContent);
        $("#my-alert").text(data.message1);
    }
});
```